# How can I show uploaded images from firebase using react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, web, firebase-storage

Good day everyone!
I’m starting to learn react and i wanted to create a simple upload form. So I am uploading images to firebase storage and I want to show them when they finish uploading, so far I’ve manage to upload them into the firebase storage but they don’t show up on the page.  What am I doing wrong? This is the method I am using to handle the event when the user clicks the upload button:

```
handleOnChange(event){
const file= event.target.files[0];
const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref(`fotos/${file.name}`);
const task = storageRef.put(file);
task.on('state_changed', (snapshot) => {
      let percentage = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100
      this.setState({
        uploadStatus: percentage,
      }),
      (error) => {
      console.error(error.message)
    },
    this.setState({
        picture:task.snapshot.downloadURL
    })
      console.log(task.snapshot.downloadURL)

    })
  }
```

This is what the component returns

```
return (
      <div>
      <progress value={this.state.uploadStatus} max="100">
        {this.state.uploadStatus}%
      </progress>

      <input type='file' onChange={this.handleOnChange.bind(this)}/>
      <div id='gallery'>

        < img src={this.state.picture}/>

      </div>
      </div>
    );
```

Both are on the same component.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is a syntax issue in how you pass arguments to `on` method. It should be something like this.

```
task.on(
  "state_changed",
  snapshot => {
    let percentage = snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes * 100;
    this.setState({ uploadStatus: percentage });
  },
  error => {
    console.error(error.message);
  },
  () => {
    this.setState({ picture: task.snapshot.downloadURL });
    console.log(task.snapshot.downloadURL);
  }
);
```

If you need multiple statements in an arrow function, you should wrap them with brackets.